# Different File Creation time between WinPe and Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-pe

I am booting WinPe from USB drive and do some driver related tasks there.
These tasks are writing logfiles to WinPe temporary ramdrive X:. The logfile name includes file creation time.

[image]

The logfiles are then copied to MainOS (Win7) harddrive c: (Still view from WinPe).

[image]

I reboot and start MainOS from harddrive.
If i view the logfiles, file time has changed. It seems like a time zone shift.

[image]

Why does this happen and what can i do to correct it ?

Comment: what is your current timezone?

Comment: Time zone
WinPe - Pacific Time
Win7 - undefined
I set it to Pacific Time also and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I have two different time zones

WinPe - Paficic time

Win7 - Undefined ? (Another issue i have to fix in my sysprepded image)

Cause i used WinPe time zone as base for logfile name, i get confused because file time is always shown with the actual time zone.

A possible solution would be to synchronize the two OS time zones. I can read MainOS offline registry to get the time zone there and switch WinPe time zone.

Comment: Can you explain a little how and why this solved your issue?

Comment: On NFTS file system, time stamp is stored in UTC. Explorer shows file with local time zone adjustment.
Cause i used the WinPe time zone as base for the logfile name, its confusing if MainOs has a different time zone.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that information